# isLucky task - CodeSignal; keeps running true even with if else statement defaulting to false

Tags: javascript

I'm doing the isLucky task on CodeSignal and my code keeps returning true. What can I do to fix this?

Task: A ticket number is considered lucky if the sum of the first half of the digits is equal to the sum of the second half.

Given a ticket number n, determine if it's lucky or not.

I've tried switching the order of the code using

```
if(first == second) {
return true;
} else { 
return false;
}


function isLucky(n) {
    var half = n.length/2;
    var first = 0;
    var second = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < half; i++) {
        first += n[i];
    }
    for(var j = half+1; j < n.length; j++) {
        second += n[j];
    }
    if(first != second) {
        return false;   
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

One of the practice tests is n = 239017; I expected it to return false, but it returns true.

Comment: What does the task say about uneven numbers? Like 55139? There is not real half.

Comment: Is `n` a number or a string?

Comment: replace `var half = n.length/2` with `var half = Math.floor(n.length/2)` so in odd cases you ignore the middle item (actually you should not have odd items but it seems you have).

Comment: @Fortuna, it says the input should always be an even number. "[input] integer n

A ticket number represented as a positive integer with an even number of digits."

Comment: @AuxTaco, when I tried converting it to a string, I had the opposite problem. The function kept returning false instead of true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`n` is a number, and numbers don't have `length` properties or numerical indices. With that in mind, we see that the important part of your code never runs:

```
function isLucky(n) {
    var half = n.length/2; // n.length is undefined; undefined / 2 is NaN

    var first = 0;
    var second = 0;

    // (0 < NaN) is false; this loop never runs
    for(var i = 0; i < half; i++) {
        first += n[i];
    }

    // NaN + 1 is NaN, (NaN < undefined) is false; this loop never runs
    for(var j = half+1; j < n.length; j++) {
        second += n[j];
    }

    // Nothing has happened since first and second were both set to 0; return true
    if(first != second) {
        return false;   
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

[Converting `n` to a string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) fixes those problems, but now `isLucky` always returns `false`. Reading through the function, we expect `first` to contain the sum of the digits of the first half of `n`, and `second` the sum of the second half. Log the values of `first` and `second` before the function returns to check that assumption:

```js
function isLucky(n) {
  n = n.toString();
  var half = n.length / 2;
  var first = 0;
  var second = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < half; i++) {
    first += n[i];
  }
  for (var j = half + 1; j < n.length; j++) {
    second += n[j];
  }
  
  console.log(first, second);
  if (first != second) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}

console.log(isLucky(239017));
```

Those aren't sums. They're not even numbers. (The stack snippet console doesn't show it, but Chrome and Firefox's consoles log numbers in color and strings in black. Those are strings.)

This is because `n[i]` is a string, and [`+` is concatenation for strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Addition_()). Convert them to numbers with [`Number(n[i])`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) or [`+n[i]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()), and `isLucky(239017)` works. Other numbers still have problems, though:

```js
function isLucky(n) {
  n = n.toString();
  var half = n.length / 2;
  var first = 0;
  var second = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < half; i++) {
    first += +n[i];
  }
  for (var j = half + 1; j < n.length; j++) {
    second += +n[j];
  }
  
  console.log(first, second);
  if (first != second) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}

console.log('239017 (should be false):', isLucky(239017));
console.log('123321 (should be true):', isLucky(123321));
console.log('123933 (should be false):', isLucky(123933));
```

Looks like the first digit of the second half isn't being included in the sum. You can see that happening in the earlier version, as well: with `second` initialized to `0`, we would expect a string concatenation with the second half of `'239017'` to be `'0017'`, but we got `'017'` instead.

Start the second loop at `half` instead of `half + 1` (and drop the diagnostic logging), and `isLucky` works properly:

```js
function isLucky(n) {
  n = n.toString();
  var half = n.length / 2;
  var first = 0;
  var second = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < half; i++) {
    first += +n[i];
  }
  for (var j = half; j < n.length; j++) {
    second += +n[j];
  }
  
  if (first != second) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}

console.log('239017 (should be false):', isLucky(239017));
console.log('123321 (should be true):', isLucky(123321));
console.log('123933 (should be false):', isLucky(123933));
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer; it's very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript Solution

```
function isLucky(n) {    
    let count = 0;
    n = String(n).split('').map(t => {return parseInt(t)});
    n.forEach( (el, i) => { (i < n.length / 2) ? count += el : count -= el });
    return count == 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution in JS

```
function isLucky(n) {
    const b = n.toString().split('')
    const y = b.length / 2;
    let c1 = 0
    let c2 = 0
    b.map((e, i) => {
        if (i+1 <= y) c1 += parseInt(e);
        if (i+1 > y) c2 += parseInt(e);
    })
    return c1 === c2
}
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to explain what you change and why this should works ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
function solution(n) {
// array from string n
    const nArr = n.toString().split('');
// split the nArr into two halfs
    const firstHalf = nArr.splice(0, nArr.length / 2);
    const secondHalf = nArr.splice(nArr.length / 2 - 1, nArr.length);
// Using reduce to sum both halfs from nArray, then compare them
    return firstHalf.sort( (a, b) => b - a).reduce( (prev, curr) => Number(prev) +  Number(curr) ) == 
            secondHalf.sort( (a, b) => b - a).reduce( (prev, curr) => Number(prev) +  Number(curr) );
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

(1). length property only works when n is in String or Array not Integer
`var half = n.length/2;`

need to convert Integer to string first.

> `n = n.toString();`

---

(2). when you need any particular numeric character from a string, you need to typecast from character to integer.

> `sum½ += parseInt(n[index])`

---

(3). first sum is stop at half, not checking character at exact index = `half`.
so second sum should start with index = `half`, instead of `half + 1`.

> `for(var j = half; j < n.length; j++) {`

---

*(4). you can optimize your last condition.

when boolean result is depending on condition, you can do*

> `return (first == second);`

```js
function solution(n) {
    n = n.toString();
    var half = n.length/2, first = 0, second = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < half; i++) {
        first += parseInt(n[i]);
    }
    for(var j = half; j < n.length; j++) {
        second += parseInt(n[j]);
    }
    return first == second;
}
console.log(solution(11));
console.log(solution(1230));
console.log(solution(134008));
console.log(solution(999999));
console.log(solution(123321));
console.log(solution(239017));
console.log(solution(261534));
console.log(solution(100000));
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
function solution(n) {
    var count = 0;
    n = String(n).split('').map(t => {return parseInt(t)});
    n.forEach( (el, i) => { (i < n.length / 2) ? count += el : count -= el });
    return count == 0;
}
```

Comment: This is quite an old question and you're not contributing anything new, this code snippet has already been posted by another person.